# Find max value in List<int[]> by specific field in the array

Tags: c#, list, linq, max

I have a `List<int[]>` where each array in fact has *two* items, e.g.

```
  // List of int[] each of them is a pair of ints
  List<int[]> list = new List<int[]>() {
    new int[] {1, 2},
    new int[] {3, 4},
    new int[] {5, 8}, // <- A pair with the maximum 1st value (5) to be found
    new int[] {0, 9}
  }
```

How can I find an item of list with the maximum 1st value? I've tryed using *Linq*:

```
list.Max(item => item[0]); // <- returns "5" when I need "int[] {5, 8}"
```

but it returns just a integer value which is `item[0]`, when I need the *entire array* to be returned. Thanks!

Comment: Can u share us your full codes of "List"? Thanks

Comment: what is the expected outcome?

Comment: MiscUtil has an extension method on IEnumerable `MaxBy`.  Usage: `list.MaxBy(l => l[0]) => returns {5, 8}`

Comment: And really, this case can be as simple as a for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to create an `ArgMax` function (which is *not provided* by standard Linq yet) as *extension method*:

```
  public static class EnumerableExtensions {
    // Arg Max 
    public static T ArgMax<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, int> selector) {
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, source))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, selector))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");

      T maxValue = default(T);
      int max = 0;
      Boolean assigned = false;

      foreach (T item in source) {
        int v = selector(item);

        if ((v > max) || (!assigned)) {
          assigned = true;
          max = v;
          maxValue = item;
        }
      }

      return maxValue;
    }
  }
```

An then use it:

```
  // Test data
  List<int[]> list = new List<int[]>() {
    new int[] {1, 2},
    new int[] {3, 4},
    new int[] {5, 1}, // <- Pair with the maximum 1st value (5) to be found
    new int[] {0, 0}
  };

  int[] max = list.ArgMax(item => item[0]); // max is int[] {5, 1} array
```

Answer (score 2):

In case a **max pair** is defined by a sum of both values use the following

```
var max = list.OrderByDescending(i => i[0] + i[1]).First();
```

Comment: This solution has O(n*logn) complexity while argmax should have O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Use Aggregate

```
var r = list.Aggregate((x, y) => x[0] > y[0] ? x : y);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me

```
List<int[]> a = new List<int[]>(){new int[]{5,2}, new int[]{3,4}};

int max= a.Max(i => i[0]);

int index = a.FindIndex(b => b[0] == max);
```

this will give you the index of the pair that has the largest first value.

and thenyou can access it like this

```
int[] myMaxPair = a[index];
```

Comment: This works, but it requires two scans of the list. You can do it in a single scan with a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'll rewrite like this:

```
// List of int[] each of them is a pair of ints
List<int[]> list = new List<int[]>() {
new int[] {1, 2},
new int[] {3, 4},
new int[] {5, 8}, // <- A pair with the maximum 1st value (5) to be found
new int[] {0, 9}
}
```

to:

```
IList<Tuple<int, int>> list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 2));
pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(3, 4));
pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(5, 8));
pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(0, 9));

Console.WriteLine(list.OrderByDescending(i => i.Item1).First());  // prints (5, 8)
```

You can also use `MaxBy` from [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) library.